# What is the size of xamarin when installed on mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

After installing xamarin on my macbook, about 20 GB of my hard disk storage vanished. Is this ordinary to take all of this space?

Comment: Yes.  If you install everything it has to install all of the Android AND iOS SDKs, build tools, emulator images, etc - as well as the Xamarin/Microsoft bits too

Comment: Cool, Thanks a lot @Jason